# How to install multiple tar archives from a .tar tarball?

Tags: linux, package-management, tar, lfs

I am just getting started with Linux from scratch and there is a long list of packages that need to be installed. I headed over to one of the official mirrors to download one .tar archive of all the different "sub-archives". **Is there any way to install all the archives contained in this archive all at once?** I am looking at lfs-packages-9.1.tar from this link: ftp://ftp.lfs-matrix.net/pub/lfs/lfs-packages/

If not, what are some other ways I can efficiently install these packages? I tried using apt install but half of them weren't available.

Comment: It would be good to [edit] this with more detail about what you're trying to do, and what you've done so far. It's not clear that what you're doing makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that link that say lfs-packages-version.tar is all of the packages in one tar.

You don't want to install these on your current host though you're supposed to install them into the directory that will become the linux OS/partition you're building.

```
tar tvf ./lfs-packages-7.0.tar 
drwxr-xr-x lfs/lfs           0 2011-10-28 22:30 7.0/
-rw-r--r-- lfs/lfs     1381988 2011-06-27 13:34 7.0/autoconf-2.68.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r-- lfs/lfs     1066685 2011-06-27 13:34 7.0/automake-1.11.1.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r-- lfs/lfs       14250 2011-06-27 13:34 7.0/bash-4.2-fixes-3.patch
-rw-r--r-- lfs/lfs     7009201 2011-06-27 13:34 7.0/bash-4.2.tar.gz
 ...
```

> Is there any way to install all the archives contained in this archive all at once?

You could script the build an install process. The process should be described in the LFS how to.

Comment: Thanks! I'm really new to this. I should have read the book more clearly; it says "download" not "install".